Poedit - 1 translation in more than 1 place with 2 different meanings
I m translating a game with Poedit and the word "cross" is used as the verb "to cross" and the noun "cross" (the plus thing) but in Poedit there aren't 2 fields for the different translations of the word, it uses the same field in both cases. In the "lang" folder of the game there is one in french and 1 in english and only the english one has this problem.
This is are the "Notes for translators" in Poedit:

‪--------
‪msgid "Traverser"
‪--------
‪msgid "Franchir"
‪RichterCross (name)
‪
‪--------
‪msgid "DLCP_CROSS_NAME"

I already translated 40% of the game already and i dont want to switch to translating the french .pot file.
Is there a way to specify when to use each translation?
I didnt try anything as i dont have experience with Poedit or PHP or other coding languages associated with it. This is my first time using Poedit and anything related
